# Galanz mini fridge buzz

Tags: refrigerator

My new fridge has been making the worst buzzing. When I looked in the back, I saw cut wires and thought I'd ask 'what is wrong with this picture?!?' Any thoughts/ideas appreciated. [image]

Comment: Green should mean ground wire.  If new fridge would return as defective.  Not your problem.

Comment: if not returnable, reconnect those wires for safety and it _might_ also help with the noise.

Comment: Take it back, the corrosion shows that it was either stored improperly or more likely used.